# Dynamically Sized UITextView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to add a paragraph of text to a `UIView` in my storyboard in the form of a non-editable, non-scrolling and non-selectable `UITextView`. I would like the `UITextView` to take up a variable number of lines based on how many it needs. It should have a fixed width and y position. How do I accomplish this in the storyboard in such a way that I can link other UI elements' constraints to the bottom of the `UITextView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a constraint pinning the text view’s height to some constant, and make an `IBOutlet` to that constraint so you can access it in code. Whenever the text changes, set the constraint’s `constant` to the text view’s `contentSize.height`:

```
textView.sizeToFit()
textView.layoutIfNeeded()
textViewHeightConstraint.constant = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(textView.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max)).height
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing Zev Eisenberg answer for Swift 3. CGFloat.max doesn't work anymore. There is now CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude

So updated version for **Swift 3** is:

```
@IBOutlet var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

textView.sizeToFit()
textView.layoutIfNeeded()
textViewHeight.constant = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.size.width, 
height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height
```

Answer (score 0):

Selected answer is not work for me. Then i found my solution;

1- Uncheck `Scrolling Enabled` property. Then, make an `IBOutlet` that constraint and write that code;

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    textViewConstraint.constant = textView.intrinsicContentSize().height
}
```